# Numerically solving integrals with singular endpoints

Tags: numerical-methods, singular-integrals, quadrature

I'd like to write a small library which uses the boundary element method to compute the charge distributions on bodies. This requires me to solve the following integrals
$$\int_{0}^{1}{\log{\sqrt{[x_i-x(t)]^2+[y_i-y(t)]^2}}\,dt}$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{[x_i-(t)]\,\vec{e}_x+[y_i-y(t)]\,\vec{e}_y}{\left\{[x_i-x(t)]^2+[y_i-y(t)]^2\right\}^2}\cdot\vec{n}_i\,dt}.$$
Sometimes it holds that $x(t)=x_i\ t\in\{0,1\}$ or $y(t)=y_i,\ t\in\{0,1\}$. However, it can be assumed that $x(t)\ne x_i\ \forall\,t\in(0,1)$ and $y(t)\ne y_i\ \forall\,t\in(0,1)$.

I tried to solve these integrals with `gsl_integration_qags`. Unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
gsl: qags.c:563: ERROR: integral is divergent, or slowly convergent
```

I also tried to use `gsl_integration_qagp` and include the endpoint in the list of singular points. According to the GSL documentation, singular points given to `gsl_integration_qagp` must lie strictly within the integration interval and so I shouldn't be surprised to get an error message which was:

```
gsl: qagp.c:494: ERROR: bad integrand behavior found in the integration interval
```

Can you please recommend me a suitable C/C++ library (function) which is able to solve the integrals mentioned above. It would also be really helpful if someone could shed some light on what kind of integration schemes are suitable for such kind of integrals.

Comment: It seems you are asking two questions: 1) an integration library and 2) the math behind it. The former question should not be asked here but instead elsewhere (e.g. StackOverflow), but we can try answering the latter question.

Comment: As long as your integrand is smooth in the interior, integrable endpoint singularities are no problem. The methods of choice would be those relying on variable transforms, moving away to infinity or dampening the singularity, so the transformed integral may be computed even with a simple trapezoidal rule. You may want to look at this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31550/Fast-Numerical-Integration

Answer (score 1):

The first integral may be handled using analytic techniques. Notice that:

$$\log\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}=\log\frac{\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}}t+\log(t)$$

which allows the first logarithm to avoid a singularity at $t=0$. Similarly, if a singularity occurs at $t=1$, then divide by $1-t$. The leftover logarithm may then be computed as

$$\int_0^1\log(t)~\mathrm dt=\int_0^1\log(1-t)~\mathrm dt=-1$$

In the event that a singularity still remains, you can apply the above multiple times.

---

The second integral does not look like it can be handled so nicely. In general, singularities when integrating may be handled using adaptive step sizes. The idea is that you sample points sparsely where the integrand is well-behaved and you sample points densely where the integrand is ill-behaved (e.g. singularity). For example, instead of sampling points every $\Delta t=0.01$, you may choose to set

1. $\min|\Delta t|=0.00001$ at the singularity.
2. $\max|\Delta f(t)|=0.1$ on the singularity.
3. $\max|\Delta t|=0.01$ away from the singularity.

so the procedure would be

1. Set $\Delta t:=\pm0.01$ ($\pm$ for going forwards or backwards).
2. Compute $f(t+\Delta t)$.
3. Compute $|\Delta f(t)|$. If it is greater than $0.1$, set $\Delta t:=\pm0.1|\Delta t/\Delta f(t)|$.
4. If $\Delta t>0.00001$, continue with the chosen method. Otherwise set $\Delta t=0.00001$ and use one left/right Riemann sum (don't use the point $f(t+\Delta t)$ because it may be troublesome).

Note that you have to start at a point which is not a singularity. Note the above is just a simple example of the concept, a more complicated formulation is given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_step_size).